# Spring Boot doesn't find mongo host specified in app.yml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I followed the tutorial on https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/.
Difference is, that my mongodb instance is not running on localhost, so I created a file application.yml containing one line as follows:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host: myhost
```

Unfortunattely, it doesn't seem to work. Main class is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`.
It works, if I use the environment variable SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST=myhost.

The yml file is placed in src/main/resources/.

Project structure:

```
com
  +- test
     +- project
         +- Application.java
         +- entities
         |   +- Person.java
         +- repos
         |   +- PersonRepository.java
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spring.data.mongodb.host: myhost` isn't the right syntax for YAML configuration. The contents of the file should be:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: myhost
```

Comment: Didn't work. :(
How can I check, if my yml config is correctly applied? I see the file in the resulting jar file (it is in the root folder there).

Comment: The exception will tell you. Using the config above you should see something like `address=myhost:27017`. If it still says `localhost` then you've made a mistake with the configuration. You've mentioned `app.yml` in the question title and `application.yml` in the body. It needs to be the latter (or `application.yaml`).

Comment: Exception states localhost. What is the right place to save the config, so that it is correctly bundeled by Maven? Filename is application.yml

Comment: `src/main/resources` is the right place for it. Sounds like you need to share your code to make any more progress.

Comment: I run an old build. :( Sorry. With the fix of the yml config format, it works now. Thanks.